# Passing Angular EventEmitter.emit() as a callback

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, callback, closures

An event emitter `exitEvent` is defined within a component `app`. The question is what if the function is called by passing as a paramater?

For example

**app.component.ts**

```
@Output() readonly exitEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

...

cancel() {
    const self = this;
    const action = {
      callback: this.exitEvent.emit.bind(self),
      callbackParam: true
    }
    action['callback'](true);
  }
```

In the above example the call will not properly done and populate error like:

```
ERROR TypeError: "observers is undefined"
    next RxJS
    emit Angular
```

Comment: What's your use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see the `emit` method is called on the context of the observable itself, not your component context. So binding it to `this` aka self is not correct. The correct implementation of your code should look as follows:

```
@Output() readonly exitEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

...

cancel() {
    const self = this;
    const action = {
      callback: this.exitEvent.emit.bind(this.exitEvent), // <-- Main change here
      callbackParam: true
    }
    action['callback'](true);
  }
```

Here you can find some [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iumab5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). However, I cannot imagine where you could need such implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the arguments and hardcoded to action. So in real scenario it is more genric to cancel something in the same UI but takes different params in conditions.

Answer (score 1):

What's your use case exactly? You can use something like this to preserve original context

```
  const action = {
    callback: (p) => this.exitEvent.emit(p),
    callbackParam: true
  }
  action['callback'](true);
```